# JQuery next class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to enable disabled drop downs and change value from json. When my program has `<select></select><select></select>` 
I mean continuous select it works fine but when there are elements in between it doesn't.

Code for index page:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <label>Item 1</label>
  <select name="item1" id="item1" class="update">
   <option value="">Select Item1</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label>Item 2</label>
  <select name="item2" id="item2" class="update" disabled="disabled">
   <option value="">Select Item2</option>
   /*output based on item1*/
  </select>
</li>
<li>
 <label>Item 3</label>
 <select name="item3" id="item3" class="update" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="">Select Item3</option>
  /*output based on item2*/
 </select>
</li>
```

Script loaded in index(as well as jquery):

```
var formObject = {
    run : function(obj) {
        if (obj.val() === '') {
            obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            var id = obj.attr('id');
            var v = obj.val();
            jQuery.getJSON('/test/mod/update.php', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
$(function() {

    $('.update').live('change', function() {
        formObject.run($(this));
    });

});
```

I know i need to change

```
obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
```

but couldnt figure it out.

Also this works with jquery 1.6.4 but not with 1.9.1 which section i need to change to update the code to be compatible with latest jquery?

Comment: When upgrading to jquery 1.9 include the migration js file as well. It includes all removed features and logs warning messages when you are using one so you know which ones to replace.  Then once done remove migration js again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have it like this

replace `obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');`
with

```
 obj.parent().next().children().removeAttr('disabled');
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/habo/7vMw8/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `.removeAttr('disabled')` use `.prop('disabled', false)`.  [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is favored as a method for updating element *properties* since 1.6, but moreso after 1.7

Answer (score 1):

The [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

You could use `.on()` instead:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '.update', function() {
    formObject.run($(this));
});
```

When using `.on()`, it is most efficient to use the closest ancestor of the elements for which the handler is to be invoked. Therefore, instead of using `document.body`, you could possibly use the `<ul>` element. It would be easier though if that element had an "id" attribute.

For dealing with the `<select>` elements not being siblings, I suggest changing occurences of the following:

```
obj.nextAll('.update').html(...
obj.next('.update').html(...
```

To this:

```
obj.closest('li').nextAll().find('.update').html(...
obj.closest('li').next().find('.update').html(...
```

Of course, you should also use `.prop()` for enabling/disabling, as suggested by @Explosion Pills.