# JQuery set default is value is passed using url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

This is a question is continuation of on my previous question on
[JQuery next class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050942/jquery-next-class)
Thanks to all the guys who helped me with that issue.

Now I have problem in setting default values. There are 2 parts.

1st Part:
Say there is a link which loads default item1, item2 and also maybe item2
What I have done is the link pass values through URL like this

```
index.php?item1=3
```

Now how do i check this and enable respectively?
I have used PHP to check and set disabled in  if nothing is passed, when passed it dosnt set disabled. but now the problem is 2nd item for which value has not been passed is disabled (item1 is enabled and set to default for the ids passed & item2, item3 are disabled) and to enable item2 I have reselect the item1.

Because, according to jquery item2 is unlocked only when item1 changes. How to override this?

2nd part: is similar to first but for certain pages item1 is set to default in code () and nothing is passed via url. Issue is same again.

I know both are of similar issues, just wondering if there is an easy solution rather than changing all part2 to part1 i.e passing item1 via url (I have to manually go into each page and change :( ).

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to check the value of Parameter by its name through [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values) link. And Check whether value is null or not.and Do perform your operation on not null value.

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
      return "";
  else
      return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

This way you can call function to get value:

```
 var Value = getParameterByName("Item1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to parse the querystring from jQuery.

**QueryString** (Taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855394/1036025))

```
(function($) {
    $.qs = (function(a) {
        if (a == "") return {};
        var b = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        {
            var p=a[i].split('=');
            if (p.length != 2) continue;
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        return b;
    })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);
```

**Javascript**

```
var item1 = $.qs('item1');

if (item1) {
    // do something...
} else {
    // set a default value...
}
```